# Is there a way to set up the Views for Perforce Workspace via bat script?

Tags: batch-file, perforce

I have my batch script as following to create the workspace, but was not able to add multiple mappings to View:

```
(
    echo Client: %p4_client%
    echo Root: %p4_root%
    echo Owner: %p4_owner%
    echo Host: %COMPUTERNAME%
    echo Options: noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
    echo View: //Depot/main/%%1     //%%p4_client%%/Projects/%%1. 
              //Depot/subfolder/... //%%p4_client%%/Projects/subfolder/...   


) | p4 client -i
```

The above would result in "wrong number of words for field view" error.

Is there a proper way to set this up?

Comment: I think there is just an `echo` missing in front of `//Depot/subfolder/…`…

Answer (score 1):

The mappings for the `View` need to start on a new line (indented).  Run `p4 client -o` to see an example of how this should look.

FWIW rather than trying to generate the spec manually I would use the global options to `p4 client -o` to generate the spec for ingestion by `p4 client -i`, something like:

```
p4 -d %p4_root% -u %p4_owner% -c %p4_client% --field Options=rmdir --field "View=//Depot/main/* //%p4_client%/Projects/*" --field "View+=//Depot/subfolder/... //%p4_client%/Projects/subfolder/..." client -o | p4 client -i
```